# NgZone timeout warnings in Chrome DevTools despite timeouts running outside the zone

Tags: javascript, angular, timeout, google-chrome-devtools, angular2-changedetection

Is it normal that you still get the warning in Chrome DevTools

```
[Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 103ms zone.js:1894
```

even when you run all your timeouts outside ngzone? I do it this way:

```
this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    this._timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    // ...
    });
});
```

and clear existing timeouts onDestroy (Angular)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that `setTimeout` runs outside Angular doesn't mean that it runs outside a zone.

As [the reference](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#runOutsideAngular) states,

> Executes the fn function synchronously in Angular's parent zone and returns value returned by the function.
>
> Running functions via runOutsideAngular allows you to escape Angular's zone and do work that doesn't trigger Angular change-detection or is subject to Angular's error handling.

So it is expected that `setTimeout` still runs within a zone.